# Долго работает mysql

Tags: php, vps, centos, mysql

Например запрос к таблице с 150к строк с сортировкой секунды 3 выполняется.

Из статистики:

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексируйте сортируемое поле.

Comment: Стало быстрее, но на чуток.